# Using Vue in Express app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, vue.js, server-side

I am new to building Node apps as well as writing Vue but figured I could create a little project to help me understand the two.

The idea is pretty simple. I'm trying to create a trivia game that can be displayed on a screen and users can use their phones to select answers to the questions that appear on the host screen. Socket.io is being used to send data between the server and clients.

Currently, there are two routes: `/` and `/host`. Connecting to `/host` will generate a unique ID (that I'm sending in the response) and create a new instance of a game, where it'll wait for "Players" to join by entering in that ID seen on the host screen.

**routes/index.js**

```
exports.host = (req, res) => {
  let id = generateRandomNumber(1000, 9999);

  res.render("host", { type: "host", gameId: id });
};

exports.player = (req, res) => {
  res.render("player", { type: "player" });
};

function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

**views/host.pug**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="ie=edge")
    title Trivia
    script.
      let gameId = #{gameId};
      let clientType = "#{type}";

  body
    main#host-container

    script(id="host-intro-template", type="text/template")
      h1 To join in, visit #[span#url example.com] on your mobile device
      h2 Enter code #[span#code= gameId]
      button Start Game
      ul#player-list

    script(id="host-question-template", type="text/template")
      span#round Round 1 of 10
      h1#question What is blah blah blah?
      ul#option-list
        li Option 1
        li Option 2
        li Option 3
        li Option 4

    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script(src="/scripts/io.js")
    script(src="/scripts/app.js")
    script(src="/scripts/main.js")
    script(src="/scripts/host.js")
```

**views/player.pug**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="ie=edge")
    title Trivia Player
    script.
      let clientType = "#{type}";

  body

    main#player-container

    script(id="player-intro-template", type="text/template")
      label(for="player-name-input") Enter Your Name
      input(id="player-name-input", type="text")
      label(for="game-code-input") Enter Code
      input(id="game-code-input", type="text")
      button(id="player-start-button", type="submit") Start

    script(id="player-waiting-template", type="text/template")
      p Waiting for game to start

    script(id="player-answer-template", type="text/template")
      ul#option-list
        li Option 1
        li Option 2
        li Option 3
        li Option 4

    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script(src="/scripts/io.js")
    script(src="/scripts/app.js")
    script(src="/scripts/main.js")
    script(src="/scripts/player.js")
```

I'd like to now incorporate Vue on the client instead of directly touching the DOM (transitions between questions, updating player list, etc.). I have a few questions on how to go about this (sorry if these are really dumb):

1. Since I generate that unique ID on the server, do I need to use Server Side Rendering to display that on the host screen right away?
2. Is there a way to get the Express server to work well with Vue's dev server? Can I run both at the same time?
3. Am I even going about this the right way?

I'm confused whether or not I need to use Server Side Rendering. The `Host` will initially have a screen that displays the unique ID of the game for the `Players` to enter on their device. There will be a list of players that have joined and a button to start the game. After hitting `start` the first question will appear and players will have time to enter their response. After the time has run out, the `Host` will show the correct answer and move on to the next, etc.

Let me know if any other information is needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Technically you're already doing server side rendering. SSR with vue is a whole nother beast, and is most likely overkill for this project. Vue's dev server is independent from Express, it's just for hot reloading code, you can certainly run both at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I understand I am doing SSR and am trying to avoid SSR with Vue as it is overkill like you said. How then, would you go about creating the Vue app? Can I display different Vue components depending on if Express matches `/` or `/host`? Should I pass a variable like I currently am in the response?

Comment: Well you just call `new Vue({})` at the bottom of `body`, after all your scripts are loaded. You can display the correct component with dynamic components, in which you pass it a variable with the component name. The docs explain it well.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't come across dynamic components. Those look promising. Thank you!